# Anyone able to get UPS on a MacBook Pro to work correctly?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, ups

I recently purchased a Tripp Lite INTERNET600U UPS for my 2016 MBP 15-inch laptop running Catalina 10.15.5.

When I connect up the USB, I get the "Your computer is running on battery power ..." dialog about once a minute.  It would be nice to get this working.  While the laptop has a battery and knows when to turn off when its battery is low, there are also external devices attached like hard drives so it would nice to gracefully shutdown when the UPS battery is low.

My current solution is to power all the disks via the USB-C ports on the laptop but that is less than ideal.

Update: I replaced the UPS with one from Cyber Power (not made in China) and the USB interface appears to work.  However, the UPS tab in the Energy Saver panel does not provide with any options on when to shutdown.  The [official Apple web page for Catalina](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-when-your-mac-shuts-down-when-using-a-ups-mchlp2987/mac) says it should and there are images to that affect on the web.  But my panel doesn't have the "Shutdown Options" button.  I assume this is because it is a laptop.

Comment: This UPS does not offer Mac software. You can use it but you will likely need to **NOT** use the USB connection. The Software is not strictly necessary for the UPS to work, however if you *want* to manage the UPS via software on your Mac you will have to find one with specific Mac compatibility.

Comment: APC UPS are compatible with the built-in support in macOS.

Comment: It seems that Tripp Lite usually works but it isn't working for me.  I can't tell if this is a change in Catalina or if it is because I'm using a laptop.

Comment: I use an APC UPS and it has the options you are missing. This device works well and is easy to setup.  I often experience power fluctuations where the voltage drops below 119V.  My UPS immediately kicks in for a few seconds until the voltage of 120V comes back.

Comment: @jmh Are you using the UPS on a laptop?  Are you running Catalina?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: no, I use it with my iMac and i'm running High Sierra.  Sorry.